# How to add a custom section in order details page in Magento 2.4?

Tags: order-details

I would like to know how to add a custom tab and corresponding panel on order details page as shown in the image.

I have already created needed table fields. I only need to show those field data on this custom panel.

Advices, tutorial links and guidelines on how to implement this are highly appriciated.

Regards,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check follow link, where found detail information :

https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-tab-admin-sales-order-view-magento-2/

Comment: Thank you Dhiren!
Well written example. Works like a charm!

Now that I can show what db fields that I needed on this section. Suppose If I want to update the same fields on the update action, what changes do I need to make on this section? Thanks.

Comment: To show data you need to do the code into the phtml and for update you can use observer event or something.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This does my job. :)